# Hibernate Criteria addOrder for @OneToMany relationship not ordering

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Let's say there is a class `A` that has a `@OneToMany` relationship to class `B`. I can add `@OrderBy` to that relationship and sort list of `B's` elements by the specified field. But how could I do the same sorting with Criteria API as I'm creating Criteria for class `A` ? (as far as I understand it'll be sorting `A's` elements by `B's` property but not the collection of `B's` elements itself)

```
public class Blog {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "BLOG_ID")
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

}
```

Query:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Blog.class)
.createAlias("categories", "bdc")
.addOrder(Property.forName("bdc.sortOrder").asc());
```

Request above doesn't sort list of categories inside Blog entry..

Comment: It will be better, if you add a simple example with persistent classes, dedulya.

Comment: @v.ladynev
I'm not sure but it seems that during the first call Hibernate executes the correct sql (with sorting), but the collection of categories isn't loaded (as it has LAZY fetch strategy). Then when collection of categories is being iterated the order is changed. If I use FetchMode.JOIN the order is correct at the end. Why is it so ?

Comment: With `FetchMode.JOIN` Hibernate loads `Blog` and `categories` with one SQL request using join. With a lazy loading Hibernate load `categories` with first access to this property. In this case your criteria is not used. Enable SQL logs to see requests.

Comment: Let us see the SQL generated?